# Swift/SwiftUI Pass different functions into a view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass in different functions into a custom styling View for a button and a NavigationLink.

```
struct commonButtonClass: View {
    let buttonText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            // a different function in each instance. it can be for example the login or register function passed in
            }
        }, label: {
            Text(buttonText)
                .font(.system(size:30))
        })
    }
}
```

However I can't find a way to pass through a function into the View. I was trying the CGFunction assignment for a variable and then passing in login() or register() in the call for this View but it does not work.

I tried a similar approach with the destination for the custom styling of NavigationLink but assigning View nor String allowed me to set it as the next destination like LoginView() or LandingView().

```
struct commonNavigationLinkClass: View {
    let target: String
// the desired destination 
    let linkText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: View(target), label: {
            Text(linkText)
                .font(.system(size:30))
        })
    }
}
```

For the button, I tried using a CGFunction class for passing the function into the button but it gave me errors that the class and contents are not compatible.

For the NavigationLink, I tried using a String with a View(//string here) but it did not work. Nor did setting the target as a class of any View.

Maybe there is a better way to go about this without passing the contents down but I'm not quite sure how to achieve the styling for all these types of button and NavigationLink otherwise. there's other styling than just font but it's just colour and borders so I removed it for simplicity sake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a closure as a parameter…

```
struct CommonButtonView: View {

    let buttonText: String
    let action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action, label: {
            Text(buttonText)
                .font(.system(size:30))
        })
    }
}
```

Then use like:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        CommonButtonView(buttonText: "Press me") {
            // some action 
        }
    }
}
```

But you're probably better off just using the regular `Button` and defining your own custom `ButtonStyle`

Comment: Thank you Ashley! this solution achieves exactly what I was looking for. Would you be willing to help with the NavigationLink destination passing in? using the same ``` destination: () -> Void ``` does not work in a similar approach as your button solution. Thank you :)

Comment: Please ask that as another question